# How do I delete record through a Join

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have an Access database where I wish to delete a record from a table using its referential entigrity  to another table.  For example I have the following two tables;

CI_Aliases with fields - CI_Ref (Primary Key) with a value of 3
and Aliase_ID (Foreign Key) with a value of 5

Aliases_Table with fields - Aliase_ID (Primary Key) with a value of 5
and Aliase with a value of "AMSS"

I have tried the following DELETE statement but I get the message "Cannot delete records from the specified table" - what am I doing wrong?

```
DELETE FROM Aliases_Table a
INNER JOIN CI_Aliases c
ON a.Aliase_ID = c.Aliase_ID
WHERE c.CI_Ref = 3
```

I should confirm that it is the record in the Aliases_Table i wish to delete but using the CI_Aliase primary key of "3"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the alias first, then the FROM clause. The syntax is a bit unintuitive

```
DELETE a.*
FROM Aliases_Table a
WHERE a.Aliase_ID IN ( 
                       SELECT
                       c.Aliase_ID 
                       FROM CI_Aliases c
                       WHERE c.CI_Ref = 3
                      )
```

Comment: Thanks.  Just tried that and now I get a message stating "Specify the table containing the records you want to delete"

Comment: Try that, access doesn't like the direct join

Comment: Thanks again but this time it presents a dialog stating 1 record will be deleted but then another dialog states "Access can't delete 1 record(s) in the delete query due to key violations and 0 record(s) due to lock violations" with options of Yes, NO and Help.  I should confirm it is the record in the Aliases_Table i wish to delete but using the CI_Aliase primary key of "3"

Comment: Cant "delete query due to key violations" means that the primary key of the "a" record is referenced somewhere else in you db

Comment: Thanks.  Doh! Of course how stupid of me as its a Foriegn key in the Other table.  I will have to work out another method

Comment: Generally you would delete that other record first, or do a "soft delete" on the "a" record by flagging it as deleted (new column would need to be added)